# Pseudo Sorting From Array

Tags: arrays, c, sorting

Problem:
An array **A** of length **N** is said to be pseudo-sorted if it can be made non-decreasing after performing the following operation at most once.

Choose an ***i*** such that ***1≤i≤N−1*** and swap ***A<sub>i</sub>*** and **A<sub>i+1</sub>**

Given an array **A**, determine if it is pseudo-sorted or not.

Input Format
The first line contains a single integer **T** - the number of test cases. Then the test cases follow.
The first line of each test case contains an integer **N** - the size of the array **A**.
The second line of each test case contains **N** space-separated integers ***A<sub>1</sub>, A<sub>2</sub>,…,A<sub>N</sub>*** denoting the array A.

Output Format
For each testcase, output **YES** if the array **A** is pseudo-sorted, **NO** otherwise.

You may print each character of **YES** and **NO** in uppercase or lowercase (for example, `yes`, `yEs`, `Yes` will be considered identical).

Constraints:

- 1 ≤ T ≤ 1000
- 2 ≤ N ≤ 10<sup>5</sup>
- 1 ≤ Ai ≤ 10<sup>9</sup>
- Sum of N over all test cases do not exceed 2⋅10<sup>5</sup>

Sample Input 1:

```
3
5
3 5 7 8 9
4
1 3 2 3
3
3 2 1
```

Sample Output 1:

```
YES
YES
NO
```

**My Solution:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int T, N, ara[100000], count, i, j;
    scanf("%d", &T);
    for (i = 0; i < T; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &N);
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
             scanf("%d", &ara[j]);
        }
        count = 0;
        for (j = 1; j < N; j++)
        {
            if (ara[j] < ara[j - 1])
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
        if (count <= 1)
        {
            printf("YES\n");
        }
        else if (count > 1)
        {
            printf("NO\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But, I am getting error in some test cases though my code is working well for the given test cases. Can anyone help me to identify the bug(s)?

[image]

Comment: Is your code working well always, but failing in some test cases nevertheless?

Comment: Actually I have tried with the given and some custom test cases and it's working. But when I am submitting the code it passes 4 out of 7 subtasks and getting WA in another 3 subtasks.

Comment: What if you try with 3 1 2?

Comment: My point is that if you compare 3 and 1, you get a failure and then if you compare 1 with 2, it is not failing, yet 3 is greater than 2 as well, therefore it should fail. Your algorithm does not tackle this case. You also compare the earlier elements again and again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test counts the number of cases where 2 adjacent numbers are out of order. This is not sufficient for the problem. Here is a counter-example:

```
1
3
3 1 2
```

`3 1 2` produces a `count` of `1` but requires 2 swaps.

Once you detect an element that is out of order, you must test if swapping it with the previous element fixes the problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int T = 0, ara[100000], count, i, j;
    scanf("%d", &T);
    for (i = 0; i < T; i++) {
        int N = 0;
        scanf("%d", &N);
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            ara[j] = 0;
            scanf("%d", &ara[j]);
        }
        count = 0;
        for (j = 1; j < N && count < 2; j++) {
            if (ara[j] < ara[j - 1]) {
                int temp = ara[j - 1];
                ara[j - 1] = ara[j];
                ara[j] = temp;
                count++;
                if (j > 1) {
                    j -= 2;
                }
            }
        }
        if (count <= 1) {
            printf("YES\n");
        } else {
            printf("NO\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You could get rid of the array and avoid converting the remaining numbers once a failure has been identified:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int T = 0, i, j;
    scanf("%d", &T);
    for (i = 0; i < T; i++) {
        int N = 0, n1 = 0, n2 = 0, n3, count = 0, c, temp;
        scanf("%d", &N);
        if (N >= 2) {
            scanf("%d%d", &n1, &n2);
            if (n1 > n2) {
                temp = n1;
                n1 = n2;
                n2 = temp;
                count++;
            }
            for (j = 2; j < N; j++) {
                n3 = 0;
                scanf("%d", &n3);
                if (n2 > n3) {
                    count++;
                    if (count > 1)
                        break;
                    if (n1 > n3) {
                        count++;
                        break;
                    }
                    n1 = n3;
                } else {
                    n1 = n2;
                    n2 = n3;
                }
            }
        }
        /* read and discard the rest of the line */
        while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
            continue;
        if (count <= 1) {
            printf("YES\n");
        } else {
            printf("NO\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Your code produces a value of 2 for count, but swapping A1 and A3 gets the array sorted so the answer should be YES instead of NO." This is not an option in this task, because the pseudo-sorted set is defined by a maximum of one swap of neighbors (!), yet, in the case of 3 2 1 the single swap that you proposed is not between neighbors. Relevant quote from the specification: "Choose an i such that 1≤i≤N−1 and swap Ai and Ai+1" (in the context of what is a valid way to convert a pseudo-sorted set to a sorted one)

Comment: @LajosArpad: you are correct. i misread the assignment.

Answer (score 2):

If you have n numbers in `ara`, then the algorithm would look like this

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int failCount = 0, i = 1, n = 3;
    int ara[3] = {3, 2, 1};
    int prevMax = ara[0] - 1;
    while ((failCount < 2) && (i < n)) {
        if (ara[i - 1] > ara[i]) {
            failCount++;
        }
        if (failCount < 2) {
            if ((i > 1) && (prevMax > ara[i])) failCount++;
            if (prevMax < ara[i - 1]) prevMax = ara[i - 1];
        }
        i++;
    }
    printf("%d", failCount);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm aware that you do not want to read all of it, so you need to read the numbers during the loop rather than read all of them before the loop, the code above was a simplified code to illustrate the logic.

Also, you need to consider examples such as

```
3 1 2
```

where 3 > 1 and that increases the counter, but later you compare 1 < 2 and it looks to be correct, yet, 3 was greater than 2 as well. This is what my second `if` is solving.

## Sample tests

`2 0 1`

[image]

Comment: @chqrlie `3 2 1` must be a **NO**, because the single swap that you propose is between the 0'th and the 2'nd element, which are not neighbors. It is a pseudo-sorted set according to the definition if you can convert it to a sorted set by swapping two neighbors once at most. In the case of `3 2 1` you can achieve that with a single swap, but not between neighbors.

Comment: my bad, I misread the assignment.

Comment: I'm afraid your implementation is not strict enough: `1 2 0` should output **NO**. Furthermore, there is no useless inner loop, nor any real performance issue. One could get rid of the array keeping only the last 3 values read and avoid converting the remainder of the line once a failure has been identified, but such optimisations seem off topic.

Comment: @chqrlie thank you for your observations, I have made adjustments to my answer's wording and code.

Comment: `int prevMax = ara[0] - 1;` does not work for `2 0 3`. you should use `if (i > 1 && prevMax > ara[i]) failCount++;` Furthermore you should perform the swap otherwise `prevMax = ara[i - 1];` is incorrect and the next test `if (ara[i - 1] > ara[i])` won't test the updated value for `ara[i - 1]`.

Comment: @chqrlie swapping is not an option because it damages the data

Comment: If you cannot modify the data, you need more complicated tests.

Comment: @chqrlie thanks for the observation. The issue was that `prevMax` was assumed to be an existent element even when `i` is 1. Edited my answer.

Comment: I'm afraid even with this fix, `2 0 1` is a counter example: your code computes 1 swap, but 2 are needed.

Comment: @chqrlie tested with `2 0 1` and it successfully determined that it's not a pseudo-sorted set. Have you tested?

Comment: @chqrlie attached a screenshot that shows that the result of the test is different from your expectation described above.

Comment: In your code, `n = 4` means you test `2 0 1 0` which actually requires 3 swaps. If you set `n = 3`, you will see that your code outputs `1` where `2 0 1` requires 2 swaps.

Comment: @chqrlie thanks for pointing it out, adjusted my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to avoid scanning the whole array to make sure that there is no more than one inversion. If we find an inversion, we also need to check if a swap will restore non-decreasingness. I guess that the code below does a minimum of comparisons.

```
int i;

// Detect the first inversion, if any (b is always a[i-1])
b= a[0];
if (b > ara[1]) {
    i= 1;
}
else {
  b= a[1];
  for (i= 2; i < n; b= ara[i], i++) {
    if (b > ara[i]) {
      // If b = a[i-1] will cause a non-decreasing sequence, fail
      if (ara[i-2] > ara[i])
        return false;
      else
        // The swap might fix the inversion
        i++;
        break;
    }
  }
}

// Detect the second inversion, if any
for ( ; i < n; b= ara[i], i++) {
  if (b > ara[i]) {
      // There is a second inversion, fail
      return false;
  }
}

return true;
```

There is a subtlety: when a first inversion is found, we check if `ara[i-2] <= ara[i]`, but not `ara[i-1] <= ara[i+1]`. In fact, we leave this second test to the detection of a second inversion, with `b` still `ara[i-1]` and continuing from `ara[i+1]`.

We also handled the first two elements differently, to avoid `ara[i-2]` being undefined.